# Apply same function to Change Letter Case of Column Names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a nested list with two data.frames, and I would like to change all variable names and variable categories to uppercase

```
my_list <- list(my_name = data.frame(c("Juan", "CArlos", "RRicardo")),
                my_data = data.frame(c("Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles")))
```

The result I am looking for is

```
$MY_NAME
c..JUAN....CARLOS....RRICARDO..
1                            JUAN
2                          CARLOS
3                        RICARDO

$MY_DATA
c..LUNES....MARTES....MIERCOLES..
1                             LUNES
2                            MARTES
3                         MIERCOLES
```

Answer (score 1):

We can loop over the `list` and apply `toupper` on the `names` as well as the column values and the names of the `list`

```
setNames(lapply(my_list, \(x) {
      x[] <- lapply(x, toupper)
      names(x) <- toupper(names(x))
       x}), 
    toupper(names(my_list)))
```

-output

```
$MY_NAME
  C..JUAN....CARLOS....RRICARDO..
1                            JUAN
2                          CARLOS
3                        RRICARDO

$MY_DATA
  C..LUNES....MARTES....MIERCOLES..
1                             LUNES
2                            MARTES
3                         MIERCOLES
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to call `toupper` three times, to replace the `names of the data.frames`, the `names of the individual data.frame columns`, and the `values in each column`
We can use the tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_list %>%
    map(~mutate(.x, across(where(is.character), toupper)) %>% #values in each column
            rename_with(toupper)) %>% # names of the individual data.frame columns
    set_names(toupper(names(.))) #names of the data.frames

$MY_NAME
  C..JUAN....CARLOS....RRICARDO..
1                            JUAN
2                          CARLOS
3                        RRICARDO

$MY_DATA
  C..LUNES....MARTES....MIERCOLES..
1                             LUNES
2                            MARTES
3                         MIERCOLES
```

The `where(is.character)` part was added for safety. We can obviate that by substituting `across(.fns=toupper)` for the original call to
`across()`